# CSS HTML : stumped on how to center this piece of text

Tags: html, css

How would I go about vertically centering the name "Tony Robbins" for this drop down menu? I've tried adding vertical-align:middle  to both the span containing the text and to the li#drop-avatar which contains the text. Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

P.S. is there also a way to get text-align: center also working so "Tony Robbins" is also centered horizontally?

http://jsfiddle.net/vJaaR/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add:

```
img
{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Because your text is inline with the image, you need to tell the image how to align with the text.

Comment: Make sure to add `margin-bottom: ##px` to this style in order to provide the bit of padding that you had before.

Answer (score 0):

span is an inline element, so it will only take up the amount of space that it needs. Consider making this span a block element using `display: block` and it will take up the full width. Then you can apply `text-align: center` to it.

You may have to float the image to the left in this case, though.

Update: I added the styles to the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dismissile/vJaaR/1/

Does this do what you want?

These are the styles I added:

```
a.small-width > span {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

a.small-width > img {
    float: left;
}
```

You might want to create new classes because I have no idea what else you use small-width for.